# In graphQL of images with Gatsby, no error occurs in develop, but in production environment it becomes an error

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm sorry, but I need your help.
I'm getting the images in the development environment without any problems, but in the production environment npm run build, I'm getting an error in the image acquisition part.

### error message

```
Cannot read property 'dir' of null
 18 |       thumbnail {
     |       ^
  19 |         childImageSharp {
  20 |           gatsbyImageData(width: 1000, formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF])
  21 |         }
  22 |       }
```

### Status.

When I run npm develop, no error occurs, the image is displayed and the intended behavior is achieved.

When I run npm run build, I get an error.

### Directory

content/blog/first/index.md

content/blog/first/top.jpg

```
---
thumbnail: "./top.jpg"
---
```

### gatsby-node.js

```
    type Frontmatter {
      thumbnail: File @fileByRelativePath
    }
```

### graphql

```js
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostBySlug(
    $id: String!
    $previousPostId: String
    $nextPostId: String
  ) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id }) {
      id
      html
      frontmatter {
        thumbnail {
          childImageSharp {
            gatsbyImageData(width: 1000, formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF])
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

```js
const thumbnail = getImage(data.markdownRemark.frontmatter.thumbnail)
~~~~~~~
 <GatsbyImage
              className="m-auto"
              image={thumbnail}
              alt={post.frontmatter.title}
            ></GatsbyImage>
```

### Supplement

I am using gatsby-starter-blog for the starter.
I'm using this configuration because I thought it would be easier to store the articles and the images used for the articles in the same directory, but I'm thinking that the location of the images could be anywhere if it makes it less difficult.

If you have any ideas, I would appreciate it if you could let me know. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: Why you are using type definitions for `thumbnail` (`fileByRelativePath`)? It seems  to be the source of the issue

Comment: thank you ! I want to use image file in same directory. if without 'fileByRelativePath' I cant use this image on develop so i have to write this.